# Remove card from game go in trash in Dead of winter?

Tags: dead-of-winter

By removing a card from your hand from the game. Does the card go in the trash pile or do we remove it from the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every card that you would put in the waste pule says for it to be placed in the waste pile.

A good example of this is resolving a crisis as you don't add those cards to the waste pile when you are done. Here is the online [rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/dead-of-winter/rules.pdf)

> Resolve Crisis: Shuffle the cards that were added face-down
>   to the crisis during the player turns phase. Reveal them
>   one at a time. Each item card added that has a symbol
>   matching a symbol in the prevent section of the crisis
>   is worth 1 point. Each card that doesn’t have a symbol
>   matching a symbol in the prevent section of the crisis
>   subtracts 1 point. After revealing all of the cards, if
>   the combined point total is lower than the number
>   of players then immediately resolve the crisis. If the
>   point total equals or exceeds the number of players
>   the crisis is prevented. Additionally, if the point total
>   exceeds the number of players by 2 or more the colony
>   gains 1 morale. After resolving the crisis, remove all
>   cards added to the crisis from the game. See Example:
>   Resolving a Crisis to lef

Comment: Important note is that to not put them in the game box or back in their deck since sometimes they are needed again. Some crossroads cards state something like, "put all food cards that has been discarded into the waste pile" or something like that.